# Jgit clone on android

Tags: android, clone, jgit

I created test android app. In app i call clone operation used jgit and i get error :

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown e69de29
org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:125)
org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:228)
org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkoutEntry(DirCacheCheckout.java:926)
org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.doCheckout(DirCacheCheckout.java:444)
org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkout(DirCacheCheckout.java:378)
org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.checkout(CloneCommand.java:224)
org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:121)
```

But in agit, this operation is executed without error. I studied code of agit, but did not understand why this is happening.

Tell me, what i doing wrong?

My code:

```
   Git.cloneRepository()
    .setBare(false)
    .setDirectory(dir)
    .setCloneAllBranches(false)
    .setRemote("origin")
    .setURI(uri)
.call();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to add setNoCheckout(true) before the call(). You have an error when checking out. You can then check out with a separate command.

For your problem, maybe no branch is set. Take a look at yourdir/.git/.../branches/ for example, or after cloning, try to find the current branch. Maybe it's not defined. The file yourdir/.git/HEAD is also interesting.